# Is it legal to crawl news from any website, maintaining a link to their news?

Tags: copyright

I want to know if it's legal to crawl some websites, let's say cnn.com and bbc.com, and display the  title, descripton, the image, as well the link to redirect to the actual link for the news?

Answer (score 2):

Currently it is legal (in most jurisdictions), but this may not be the case for much longer.

The EU is working on a new provision in copyright law called [Publisher's right](https://www.publishersright.eu/). If it makes it into law, it would require operators of commercial search engines (i.e. Google, Bing, etc.) to *license* the right to crawl websites from publishers.

Comment: How much of the content would this cover (could google seach include the title and meta-description of articles, and what about structured data?)

Comment: @jrtapsell As I understand "Publisher's right", it is not about quantity of content, but about crawling. So nothing would be allowed without a license.